# x11vnc server - creating multiple zombie processes - how do I stop it?

Tags: server, 10.04, vnc

Recently started using x11vnc server on Ubuntu (10.04) for remote access over internet from win$ PC using SSL/SSH vnc viewer.

Thought I had it config'd ok then noticed **many** zombie processes for x11vnc, like 20+ in sys monitor sometimes.

I'm using terminal cmd: `x11vnc -rfbversion 3.6 -rfbport 5900 -rfbauth /home/xxxx/.vnc/passwd -forever -bg -gui tray` to start it.

How can I stop/avoid it creating the zombies every connect/disconnect?

Comment: After you have finished with x11vnc, `pkill x11vnc` might work.

Comment: won't this kill x11vnc for future connections? This is an unattended pc which i need x11vnc to be running at all times. thanks for the interest.

Answer (score 0):

Running `pkill x11vnc` should stop x11vnc plus any zombie processes it creates.

This will just send the signal `SIGTERM` for the program to terminate, and you will be able to run `x11vnc` after `pkill`ing the previous instance of it.

Comment: as I said, this is an unattended pc, how would I restart x11vnc when I cannot access the remote pc, x11vnc has been killed?

Comment: Either **A)** ignore the zombie processes, they are probably `x11vnc` itself anyway **B)** Create a bash script to execute it a certain times etc. Ignoring 'em may be best.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to clean all hung sessions

```
`x11vnc -clear-all`
```

Comment: That's not at all what this does.  First, it's `--clear_all`, with 2 dashes and an underscore.  Second, this option doesn't clear defunct sessions, it tells the x11vnc server to explicitly release the modifier keys (shift, ctrl, numlock, etc.) when entering and exiting the session to prevent any of them from getting stuck on.